# Creating an assignment (=) operator for class in C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

**EDIT 2**

I was using insert(...) incorrectly, I didn't actually need a '=' operator.  Sorry to waste peoples' time.  I have voted to close.. 2 votes remain.  Please vote.

**EDIT**

The reason I want an '=' operator is so I can use the insert(...) function on a vector of Derivation objects.  At the moment my compiler says:

`/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:283: error: no match for 'operator=' in '* __result = * __first'`

I have created '==' and '<' operators for my own classes before but I'm struggling to create an '=' operator.  My class looks like this (ignore the silly variable names):

```
class Derivation {
public:
    string                  rc; 
    ImplementationChoice    Y; 
    vector<Derivation>      X;
    vector<string>          D;       
    vector<string>          C;       
    vector<Player>          P, O;   
    vector<Attack>          B;   

    // various functions
    // ...
};
```

and I want to know what I need to put in

```
// What do '=' return?  An object of the class right?
Derivation& operator=(const Derivation &d) const {
    // something....
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: At the very least, it should return a reference (`Derivation&`) rather than a new copy of the object. :)

Comment: Thank you.. editing post now.  Sorry.. pretty new to C++

Comment: I recommend you read the [operator overloading faq](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/46642).

Comment: If ImplementationChoice already provides an `operator=` it's likely that an appropriate `Derivation::operator=` has already been implicitly declared. (Not putting in an answer since it doesn't really address your questions, just putting this as a heads up.)

Answer (score 2):

This is up to you, really.  What do you need the operator to do?  Do you want to return a reference, or do you want a copy?

EDIT: Please note that this was rhetorical.  What you use this vector for will determine if you need a reference or a copy.  For example, if the object your inserting is at any point going to go out of scope before being removed from the vector, you'll want a copy.  If not, and you want the original object to be effected when you change the instance in the vector, you'll want a reference.  Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Please so EDIT in post.  I need the '=' operator so I can use insert(...) on a vector of Derivation objects

Comment: I want to be able to do this: 
`vector<Derivation> d;` 
`d.insert(d.end(), vec.begin(), vec.end());`

Comment: From you edit and looking at what I want to do, I believe it is a reference that I need.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

first remove the const ...
then **if you really need a copy operator**, do something like that and add your own logic (so that it doesn't do just exactly what would be done with the compiler generated copy operator) :

```
Derivation& operator=(const Derivation& other) {
    this->rc = other.rc; 
    this->Y = other.Y; 
    this->X = other.X;
    this->D = other.D;       
    this->C = other.C;       
    this->P = other.P;
    this->O = other.O;   
    this->B = other.B;
    // ...
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Except that this is ***exactly*** what the compiler-generated copy-assignment operator does...

Comment: @Armen - really? I didn't realise that the compiler generated assignment operator calls the assignment for the `vector` members too?

Answer (score 2):

First, an assignment operator probably should not be const--

Second, assignment operators usually return a non-const reference to the object that was assigned a value (*this)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need one. The compiler-generated one will do just fine.

Comment: That depends on how are implemented ImplementationChoice, Player and Attack...

Comment: really? there are five `vector`s in this `struct`...

Comment: Please so EDIT in post.  I need the '=' operator so I can use insert(...) on a vector of Derivation objects.  It doesn't compile without one.  It says `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:283: error: no match for 'operator=' in '* __result = * __first'`

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to implement an assignment operator is copy-and-swap.
This has the advantages of being the most simple way to make an assignment operator that is correct in the face of exceptions and self-assignment. It also defines the assignment operation in terms of the copy-constructor, thus reducing the number of places where your code needs to be changed if you add extra members to the class.

Anyway - here is what it looks like in your case:

```
class Derivation {
    public:
    string                  rc; 
    ImplementationChoice    Y; 
    vector<Derivation>      X;
    vector<string>          D;       
    vector<string>          C;       
    vector<Player>          P, O;   
    vector<Attack>          B;   

    //You need to add a swap function to your class
    void swap(Derivation& o) {
        rc.swap(o.rc);
        Y.swap(o.Y);//Assuming ImplementationChoice has a swap function (it should!)
        X.swap(o.X);
        D.swap(o.D);
        C.swap(o.C);
        P.swap(o.P);
        O.swap(o.O);
        B.swap(o.B);
    }
    Derivation& operator=(Derivation const& o) {
        Derivation copy(o);
        copy.swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }
    // various functions
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you Mankarse.  Did you see my EDIT in my post?  Is this what I need if I want to use the vector insert(...) function on a vector of my Derivation objects?  Thanks.

Comment: @alemaster - No, the insert function will use the copy-constructor to insert the Derivation objects into the vector. The compiler-generated copy-constructor should be fine for this class.

Answer (score 0):

to overload assignment operator you should do this

```
Derivation& operator=(const Derivation &d)  {
    // something....
   return *this
}
```

This will allow you to do something like.

Deviation a, b, c;
//something

c = b = a;

Comment: I don't think it should be a const method as you're changing the state of the object (assigning it the value of `d`). It's probably legal C++ but doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Thank you.. I basically had the single argument parameter (const Derivation &d) from pasting from a '<' operator elsewhere in my code.  I can remove that right?  Thanks.

Comment: @alemaster remove what. I dont quite understand

Comment: @Leon - ignore me!  I have only just realised the '=' must have exactly one argument.  I tried removing `const Derivation &d` but the compiler complained.

Answer (score 0):

Since - @jalf has not put up an answer, here it is :)

```
Derivation& operator=(const Derivation &d) {
  // something....
  return *this;
}
```

You need to return a reference to this instance. `this` is a keyword which holds a pointer to the instance on which the operator is acting.